# Add duplicate elements in sparse matrix representation in C

Tags: c, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix which is represented as: int pattern[2][N]; double val[N]. pattern[0] and pattern[1] store row and column number respectively. val stores the element value. In my case, N is very large like 1 billion. But the problem is lots of 'val' have duplicate 'pattern'. For example

```
pattern[0][0] = 1; pattern[1][0] = 1; val[0] = 2;
pattern[0][1] = 1; pattern[1][1] = 1; val[1] = 3;
pattern[0][2] = 1; pattern[1][2] = 1; val[0] = 4;
```

Now I want to add those duplicate elements together to reduce the storage memory. I tried to define a structure which is

```
struct sparmat{
     int row;
     int col;
     double val;
}
```

Then create a structure array and initialize it by those data. After that, I can use qsort to sort this array so that I can add those duplicate elements together quickly. But this process requires more memory since I have to change the data structure first and I don't have so much memory in my server. So does anybody have a clue of how to solve this problem efficiently without large memory requirement? Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered a hash table with a hash of row and col as keys?

Comment: @CharlieBurns I never use a hash table before. Can you give me more details? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is the data coming from a file or some existing data structure? It says you have a sparse matrix in 'int pattern[2][N]; and double val[N];' Does that exist in memory already?

Comment: Yes, those data come from some existing data structure.

Comment: Is this unix or windows?

Comment: It's unix in this case.

Comment: See my proposal below. How many unique row,col entries do you think this thing has?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we talked about before...

There are 4 files below, sm.h, main.c, sm.c and gen.c. The interface is defined in sm.h, main.c shows how to use the interface, sm.c is the implementation, gen.c is a C program that creates a test input file for main.c.

I'd suggest studying sm.h and main.c carefully. Thanks.

The interface is defined in sm.h

```
#ifndef __SM_H__
#define __SM_H__

typedef struct sm_entry_s sm_entry_s;
typedef struct sm_search_s sm_search_s;
typedef struct sm_hash_s sm_hash_s;

// creates a sparse matrix
sm_hash_s *sparse_matrix_create(int estimate) ;

// puts a value into the sparse matrix at row,col
// if an entry exists at row,col, value is added to the entry
// if an entry does not exist, it creates one and sets it to value
double sparse_matrix_put(sm_hash_s *sm, unsigned row, unsigned col, double value) ;

// return the current value at row,col. If no entry, returns 0.0
double sparse_matrix_get(sm_hash_s *sm, unsigned row, unsigned col) ;

// frees the memory used by the sparse matrix
void sparse_matrix_free(sm_hash_s *sm) ;

// print some stats to stdout
void sparse_matrix_stat(sm_hash_s *sm) ;

// dump the matrix to stdout ( ugly )
void sparse_matrix_dump(sm_hash_s *sm) ;

// return a pointer for use in sparse_entry ( see below )
sm_search_s *sparse_matrix_search(sm_hash_s *sm) ;

// gets the next entry in the sparse matrix search
// returns 0 when there are no more entries
int sparse_entry(sm_search_s *p, unsigned *prow, unsigned *pcol, double *pval) ;

#endif
```

An example of how to use the interface is in main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "sm.h"

// expects lines of the form %u %u %lf ( row, col, value )
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    unsigned row, col;
    double d;

    sm_hash_s *sm = sparse_matrix_create(32);
    while(scanf("%u %u %lf", &row, &col, &d) == 3) {
        sparse_matrix_put(sm, row, col, d);
    }

    // print some statistics
    sparse_matrix_stat(sm);

    // dump the whole ugly thing out
    // sparse_matrix_dump(sm);

    // print a line for each entry
    sm_search_s *s = sparse_matrix_search(sm);
    while(sparse_entry(s, &row, &col, &d)) {
        printf("%u %u %lf\n", row, col, d);
    }
    free(s);

    sparse_matrix_free(sm);

    return 0;

}
```

The implementation is in sm.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "sm.h"

#define public /* nothing */

// change to 1 for debugging
#define debug if(0) printf

struct sm_entry_s {
    sm_entry_s  *next;
    unsigned    row;
    unsigned    col;
    unsigned    index;
    double      value;
};

struct sm_hash_s {
    sm_entry_s **buckets;
    unsigned nentry;
    unsigned nbucket;       /* hash table bucket count */
    unsigned tableMask;     /* hash table mask */
    unsigned tableCapacity;     /* hash table capacity */
    unsigned alloced;
    unsigned freeed;
};

struct sm_search_s {
    sm_hash_s   *sm;
    int i;
    sm_entry_s  *next;
};

static void *sm_alloc(sm_hash_s *sm, unsigned n) {
    void *p = calloc(1, n);
    if(p == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "calloc(%d) failed\n", n);
        exit(1);
    }
    if(sm) {
        sm->alloced += n;
    }
    return p;
}

static void sm_free(sm_hash_s *sm, void *f, unsigned n) {
    sm->freeed += n;
    free(f);
}

/// Round up to next higher power of 2 (return x if it's already a power
/// of 2).
static int pow2roundup (int x) {
    assert(sizeof(x) == 4);
    if (x < 0)
        return 0;
    --x;
    x |= x >> 1;
    x |= x >> 2;
    x |= x >> 4;
    x |= x >> 8;
    x |= x >> 16;
    return x+1;
}

static void sm_init(sm_hash_s *sm) {
    sm->buckets = sm_alloc(sm, sm->nbucket * sizeof(*sm->buckets));
    sm->tableMask = sm->nbucket - 1;
    sm->tableCapacity = 14*sm->nbucket/16;
}

static unsigned int hash_row(unsigned int x) {
    x = ((x >> 16) ^ x) * 0x45d9f3b;
    x = ((x >> 16) ^ x) * 0x45d9f3b;
    x = ((x >> 16) ^ x);
    return x;
}

static unsigned int hash_col(unsigned int x) {
    x = ((x >> 16) ^ x) * 0x3335b369;
    x = ((x >> 16) ^ x) * 0x3335b369;
    x = ((x >> 16) ^ x);
    return x;
}

static unsigned int hash_index(sm_hash_s *p, unsigned row, unsigned col) {
    unsigned h = hash_row(row) ^ hash_col(col);
    //printf("h = %x\n", h);
    return h & p->tableMask;
}

static void rehash(sm_hash_s *sm) {
    sm_entry_s **oldtable = sm->buckets;
    int oldsize = sm->nbucket;
    sm_entry_s *ent, *newent;

    sm->nbucket *= 2;
    debug("rehash new size = %u\n", sm->nbucket);
    sm_init(sm);
    for(int i=0; i<oldsize; i++) {
        for (ent=oldtable[i]; ent; ent=newent) {
            newent = ent->next;
            ent->next = sm->buckets[ent->index & sm->tableMask];
            sm->buckets[ent->index & sm->tableMask] = ent;
        }
    }
    sm_free(sm, oldtable, oldsize * sizeof(sm_entry_s *));
}

public sm_hash_s *sparse_matrix_create(int nbucket) {
    assert(sizeof(unsigned) == 4);
    sm_hash_s *p = (sm_hash_s *)sm_alloc(0, sizeof(*p));
    p->alloced = sizeof(*p);
    p->nbucket = pow2roundup(nbucket);
    sm_init(p);
    return p;
}

static sm_entry_s *sm_find(sm_hash_s *sm, unsigned index, unsigned row, unsigned col) {
    for(sm_entry_s *p = sm->buckets[index]; p; p = p->next) {
        if(p->row == row && p->col == col) {
            return p;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

public double sparse_matrix_put(sm_hash_s *sm, unsigned row, unsigned col, double value) {
    unsigned index = hash_index(sm, row, col);
    sm_entry_s *p = sm_find(sm, index, row, col);
    if(p == 0) {
        p = sm_alloc(sm, sizeof(*p));
        p->row = row;
        p->col = col;
        p->value = 0;
        p->index = index;
        p->next = sm->buckets[index];
        sm->buckets[index] = p;
        if(sm->nentry++ > sm->tableCapacity) {
            rehash(sm);
        }
    }
    p->value += value;
    return p->value;
}

public double sparse_matrix_get(sm_hash_s *sm, unsigned row, unsigned col) {
    sm_entry_s *p = sm_find(sm, hash_index(sm, row, col), row, col);
    return p ? p->value : 0.0;
}

public void sparse_matrix_free(sm_hash_s *sm) {
    sm_entry_s **pp = sm->buckets;
    for(int i = 0; i < sm->nbucket; i++, pp++) {
        while(*pp) {
            sm_entry_s *next = (*pp)->next;
            sm_free(sm, *pp, sizeof(*pp));
            *pp = next;
        }
    }
    free(sm->buckets);
    free(sm);
}

public void sparse_matrix_stat(sm_hash_s *sm) {
    unsigned count = 0;
    unsigned max = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < sm->nbucket; i++) {
        int n = 0;
        for(sm_entry_s *p = sm->buckets[i]; p; p = p->next) {
            n++;
        }
        count += n;
        if(n > max) max = n;
    }
    unsigned avg = count / sm->nbucket;
    printf("%u alloc, %u free, %u in use\n",
        sm->alloced, sm->freeed, sm->alloced - sm->freeed);
    printf("%u buckets, %u entries, %u max, %u avg\n",
        sm->nbucket, count, max, avg);
}

public void sparse_matrix_dump(sm_hash_s *sm) {
    for(int i = 0; i < sm->nbucket; i++) {
        sm_entry_s *p = sm->buckets[i];
        if(p) {
            printf("[%u] ", i);
            for( ; p; p = p->next) {
                printf(" [%u %u %lf]", p->row, p->col, p->value);
                printf(" %p", p);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}


static int search_next(sm_search_s *p, int i) {
    //printf("start %d\n", i);
    for( ; i < p->sm->nbucket; i++) {
        if(p->sm->buckets[i]) {
            p->i = i;
            p->next = p->sm->buckets[i];
            //printf("next is in %d %p\n", i, p->next);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    //printf("no more\n");
    p->next = 0;
    return 0;
}

public sm_search_s *sparse_matrix_search(sm_hash_s *sm) {
    sm_search_s *p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
    if(p == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc(%ld) failed\n", sizeof(*p));
        exit(1);
    }
    p->sm = sm;
    p->i  = 0;
    p->next = 0;
    search_next(p, 0);
    return p;
}
public int sparse_entry(sm_search_s *p, unsigned *prow, unsigned *pcol, double *pval) {
    if(p->next) {
        sm_entry_s *e = p->next;
        *prow = e->row;
        *pcol = e->col;
        *pval = e->value;
        if(e->next) {
            p->next = e->next;
        } else {
            search_next(p, p->i + 1);
        }
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Gen.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>

unsigned get_rand(unsigned min, unsigned max) {
    unsigned u = min + (random() % (int)(max - min + 1));
    assert(u >= min);
    assert(u <= max);
    return u;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    if(argc != 3 || !isdigit(*argv[1])  || !isdigit(*argv[2])) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s %%u %%u\n", argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }

    unsigned long N = strtoul(argv[1], 0, 0);
    unsigned long C = strtoul(argv[2], 0, 0);
    srandom(time(0));
    for(int i = 0; i < C; i++) {
        unsigned long row = get_rand(0, N-1);
        unsigned long col = get_rand(0, N-1);
        printf("%lu %lu 1.0\n", row, col);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I think there are 5 million unique rows and cols in this case, just a rough guess. And yes, it's not a homework assignment. I got those data from other fellows so that I can't change the data structure now.

Comment: The code for 5 million entries ran on my macbook in about 8 seconds, including reading and writing all the entries. Let me know how it works for you.

Comment: You can email me at crb at sonic dot net . That's probably a better way to communicate from now on. Thanks.

Comment: I tested your code with another set of data which has less entries. It works very well. I'm gonna learn those implementation details carefully. I may bug you if I meet further questions when testing more data. I never realized how powerful hash table is until today. Thank you for teaching me this important lesson: )

Answer (score 0):

I do not think some special data structure will help much if, as the OP says "duplicates" (2x).

But if there are many triplicate, quadruplicates, etc. consider an array overlaying the `val`.  I would use an unused bit in row or column to flag if the union is a single `val`, or an array of `val`s.  Further, other bits could be used to determine the array length, or the array could be determined with a special value (NaN?).

Reducing data size requirements may help.

```
// Use smallest types that fit the range of row/column
typedef unsigned short RowType;
typedef unsigned long ColType;

// Use float unless high precision is needed
typedef float ValType;

struct sparmat {
  RowType row;
  ColType col;
  union {
    ValType val;
    ValType vals[];
}
```